# ¿Cómo puedo mantener la sesión de un login al moverme de una pestaña a otra por mi Web usando cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery

El funcionamiento sería que cuando un usuario se logea mediante un login, unos botones del navbar se habilitan. Hasta aquí todo bien, pero cuando entro en uno de esos botones, los demás botones se deshabilitan y no se como hacer para que me lea las cookies y me mantenga la sesión. Si le doy al home, tampoco me mantiene la sesiones y están todos los botones deshabilitados.

Esta es la función para el login:

```
     function Comprueba()
{
  var user = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
  $.post("conexion.php",{usuario:user,password:pass},function(data)
  {
      if(data!="NO"){ 
        $("#mensaje").html("<span class='verde'>Bienvenido "+ data+ "</span>");     
        
        $("#Noticias").removeClass( "disabled");
        $("#Noticias").addClass( "active");
        
        $("#Rutas").removeClass( "disabled");
        $("#Rutas").addClass( "active");
        
        $("#Inscribirse").removeClass( "disabled");
        $("#Inscribirse").addClass( "active");
        
        $("#Listados").removeClass( "disabled");
        $("#Listados").addClass( "active");

        document.cookie = user=pass;
        var x = document.cookie;
        window.alert(x);

        limpiarFormulario();        
      }
     else
     {  
        $("#mensaje").html("<span class='roja'>Usuario no válido</span>");
     }
  });   
}
```

Con php si sabría hacerlo porque mediante método post recibes los dos parámetros usuario y pass y lo guardas en la sesión, haces una comprobación al entrar en cada pestaña y listo, pero con cookies no tengo ni idea y tampoco se si seria mejor opción usar localStorage o sessionStorage. Espero puedan ayudarme gracias.

Comment: Puedes usar localstorage para guardar los datos. Sessionstorage se pierde al salir de la pestaña

Comment: No sé mucho sobre el tema pero si que debes tener cuidado de como manejas los datos del usuario. Es una terrible idea guardar el usuario y la contraseña como tal. Lo que se suele hacer es usar algún algoritmo de digestión como SHA e incluso "agregarle sal" y guardar el resultado. Para almacenarlo localmente deberías seguir unas reglas similares

Comment: En el caso de mantener la sesión iniciada lo típico es que el servidor haga consultas al cliente para saber si sigue conectado, sino cierras la sesión. Son operaciones delicadas que no se deberían llevar a cabo desde el frontend.

Comment: Se que no hay que realizarlo guardando datos sensibles desde el frontend pero estoy tratando de aprender a usar las cookies y estoy aprovechando una web que tenia para hacerlo con un login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He creado una función para comprobar que si en sessionStorage hay datos, que elimine el disable de los botones, así mismo también hay que asegurarse que la llamada a la función se produce una vez han cargado los elementos (en mi caso el navbar) ya que si no, no produce los efectos deseados (eliminar el disable con removeClass). Y asegurarse que los archivos js se cargan al principio de la página.

```
     function Comprueba()
{
  var user = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
  $.post("conexion.php",{usuario:user,password:pass},function(data)
  {
      if(data!="NO"){ 
        $("#mensaje").html("<span class='verde'>Bienvenido "+ data+ "</span>"); 
        sessionStorage.setItem('usuario', user); //aqui guardo en 'usuario' el nick del usuario que se va a logear.    
        
        $("#Noticias").removeClass( "disabled");
        $("#Noticias").addClass( "active");
        
        $("#Rutas").removeClass( "disabled");
        $("#Rutas").addClass( "active");
        
        $("#Inscribirse").removeClass( "disabled");
        $("#Inscribirse").addClass( "active");
        
        $("#Listados").removeClass( "disabled");
        $("#Listados").addClass( "active");
         
        limpiarFormulario();        
      }
     else
     {  
        $("#mensaje").html("<span class='roja'>Usuario no válido</span>");
     }
  });   
}
```

Con esta función compruebo al cambiar de pestañas si en localStorage hay algo guardado para mantener los botones activos.

```
 function comprobarCookies()
{ 

   var x = sessionStorage.getItem('usuario');
  if(x != null)

  {
        $("#Noticias").removeClass( "disabled");
        $("#Noticias").addClass( "active");
        
        $("#Rutas").removeClass( "disabled");
        $("#Rutas").addClass( "active");
        
        $("#Inscribirse").removeClass( "disabled");
        $("#Inscribirse").addClass( "active");
        
        $("#Listados").removeClass( "disabled");
        $("#Listados").addClass( "active");

        window.alert("funciona");
  }
}
```

En el caso de querer cerrar sesión solo habría que añadir una función asi:

```
    function cerrarSesion()
{
    sessionStorage.clear(); //esto borra todo del storage pero se puede elegir que borrar y que no.
}
```

Edit: He estado haciendo comprobaciones y no es un buen funcionamiento el usar cookies para un login, claramente funciona mejor usando localStorage o sessionStorage por lo que edito la respuesta.